# How can i sorting my id in php?

Tags: php, sorting

How can i sorting my ids in php i have try like this but not showing good response 
Here is my code

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sites ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $site_id  = $row["id"];  

   

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(mon_id) FROM status Where site_id='$site_id'");  
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))  
{  
  
$mon_id = $row2['COUNT(mon_id)']; 
echo $mon_id;?><br /><?php
//try to sort my ids

   $mon_id= rsort($mon_id);
}  }}
```

and get result 
    2
    2
    1
    7
    1
    1
    5
    1
    2
    1

So how can i sorting this result

```
    7
    5
    2
    2
    2
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
```

Comment: `order by aliased_count desc;`

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, you are querying twice and your second query is executed for each row of the first query result. Therefore, you rsort is executing 10 times, but each time only for one row.

I assume that you want the counts of status for each site?!
Then you may use this query instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(status.mon_id) as cnt, status.site_id 
FROM status, sites 
WHERE status.site_id=sites.id 
GROUP BY sites.id 
ORDER BY sites.id, cnt 
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This query orders first by sites.id and then by cnt and limits the result to 10. 
So, you only need one query.

**insert your database connection information**

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
die("Keine Verbindung möglich: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(status.mon_id) as cnt, status.site_id 
                        FROM status, sites 
                        WHERE status.site_id=sites.id 
                        GROUP BY sites.id 
                        ORDER BY sites.id, cnt DESC 
                        LIMIT 10");  
if($result!=false){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))  
    {    
        $mon_id = $row['cnt']; 
        echo $mon_id."<br />";        
    }
}else{
    echo "mysql error";
}
```

Comment: i have change site to Site from all your code and it work like this.

1
1
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
1
1

but i want to show this  
2
2
2
1

Comment: Ok, change "ORDER BY Sites.id, cnt DESC" to "ORDER BY cnt DESC"

Comment: i have change this and it showing same result
and that is same as my question when i have post my problem on here...

Comment: i want to sort all the reuslt like this 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 its showing like this 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 4 1

Comment: i need some more help.how can i show site name  with ids

Comment: I really want to help you, but I suggest that you learn php and sql by yourself first. Doing and finding solutions for those problems by yourself will extreamly increase your skills...

Comment: i have no any issue  all the my requirement .Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Add `order by` to the `count`. Try with -

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(mon_id) as total FROM status Where site_id='$site_id'");  
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))  
{  

$mon_id[] = $row2['total']; 
}
```

Store the counts to an array then implement `rsort()` to it.

```
rsort($mon_id);
```

Comment: its same result like as my result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sites ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$mon_id = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(mon_id) FROM status Where site_id='.$row['id']);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {  
                $mon_id[] = $row2['COUNT(mon_id)'];
            }
        }
    }
    rsort($mon_id);
    foreach ($mon_id as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d2c7/7

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$sql = 'select *, count(mon_id) as sum_id from Sites as si
        inner join status as st
        on si.id = st.site_id
        group by st.site_id
        order by sum_id desc';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['id'] . ' - ' . $row['sum_id'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: There is probably an error. maybe your table name is "Sites" I typed "sites" that could fix the problem.

Comment: i have change sites with Sites but its same mean just blank page

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/

Comment: Fixed. But dude you make no effort at all